# Validating that only certain values are unset

Tags: python, unit-testing, null

I am checking data output in some testing code, and only some fields can be None, but I think this can be better:

```
for key in data[0].keys():
        self.assertIn(key, data_model)
        if data[0][key] is None:
            self.assertTrue('rate' in key or 'percentage' in key or 'ratio' in key)
            continue
        self.assertIsInstance(data[0][key], data_model[key])
```

Mostly I don't like the ... or ... in the `assertTrue`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things:

- your indentation looks weird
- you could store `data[0]` in some variable with a relevant name.
- you could iterate over both keys and values with [`iteritems()` /`items()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems)
- you do not need `continue` here. A simple `else` would do the trick and is more explicit.
- The line you don't quite like could be replaced by something like :

`self.assertTrue(any(w in key for w in ('rate', 'percentage', 'ratio')))`

The resulting code would be :

```
first_data = data[0]
for key, val in first_data.items():
    self.assertIn(key, data_model)
    if val is None:
        self.assertTrue(any(w in key for w in ('rate', 'percentage', 'ratio')))
    else:
        self.assertIsInstance(val, data_model[key])
```

Comment: Thanks - any was exactly what I wanted, just hadn't thought of it.  Also good suggestion about items(), and I agree about the else